# Confbridge DTMF detection

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I have created a confbridge menu in which when user press 1 or 2 it comes out of conference...Basically I want that when user press 1 in conference it returns to previous menu after leaving conference and when press 2 in conference it return to previous menu after leaving conference. So I am unable to understand how can I get that whether user press 1 or 2,So on this basis I will return user to respective menu. Please guide if any idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dialplan_exec in menu

> dialplan_exec
>
> (context,exten,priority)
>
> Allows one to escape from the conference and execute commands in the
>   dialplan. Once the dialplan exits, the user will be put back into the
>   conference.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+10